# Define and reuse inline component in Vue3

Tags: javascript, vue-component, vuejs3

Is it possible to define a "sub component" inline in Vue3 which can be reused in the same .vue file/component, but without actually defining a new `.vue` file (i.e. without defining this sub component as a new component).

The use case is that I have a very specific way of formatting `<select>` options which is used for multiple `<select>`s within the same component (`.vue` file), but which will not be used anywhere else (it's also small, so I am inclined to define this options formatting part inline). I don't necessarily want to copy and paste the formatting (and it would be good to keep it within the same .vue file because it's small).

I realise that this is only syntactic sugar which may or may not be relevant in specific cases (I'm also not seeking advice on whether or not this is a good idea). I'm just looking for a way this can be done (if not, that's also an answer ;-))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `h()` function to create vnodes inside your `setup` script in vue 3.

for example:

```js
<template>
<MyComponent />
</template>
<script setup>
const MyComponent = h('div', { class: 'bar', innerHTML: 'hello' })
</script>
```

vue document will help you completely. [document](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#v-on)

Comment: and how am I going to get multiple `<div class='bar'>hello</div>` (the return value of `h(...)`) into my template?

Comment: I've added into template as a component, did you mean that? @orange

Comment: QUESTION: How do you properly pass slots with this method, such that you can have `<MyComponent />Some custom content</MyComponent>` ?

Comment: In [document](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#rendering-slots) there is some examples to show how to use slot in `h` render function

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this in Vue2

```
Vue.component('my-checkbox', {
  template: '<div class="checkbox-wrapper" @click="check"><div :class="{ checkbox: true, checked: checked }"></div><div class="title">{{ title }}</div></div>',
  data() {
    return { checked: false, title: 'Check me' }
  },
  methods: {
    check() { this.checked = !this.checked; }
  }
});
```

Probably still works

Comment: ... and use `my-checkbox` in the main component? Yeah, possibly. I was hoping for a solution that would be declarative (i.e. declared within the `<template>`).

Comment: It's probably impossible